# My view's 'more' link needs to go to a page with exposed filters already selected

Tags: tokens, views

I have a view that is a list of a certain content. The more link for the view needs to link to a page I have set up that has exposed filters for sorting the content.

So let's say the view I have is of baseball-related content. The more link will go to another page that contains all sports, but in this case it will link there but already have the baseball filter selected. Confused?

What I had been trying was to use the Custom URL field in the view, but no tokens can be used. Maybe this isn't even the right way to go about it. I'd love to know what is.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My coworker came up with this. Works flawless. It was put in the file views_and_panels.module file created by one of our features.

```
 /**
 * Implement hook_panels_pane_content_alter().
 *
 * Add more links to the appropriate panels.
 */
function module-name_views_and_panels_panels_pane_content_alter($content, $pane, $args, $context) {
  if($pane->subtype == 'node:field_related_products') {
    if($context['argument_entity_id:node_1']->data) {
      $values = field_get_items('node', $context['argument_entity_id:node_1']->data, 'field_catalog');
      $tids = array();
      if($values) {
        foreach($values as $value) {
          $tids[]  = $value['tid'];
        }
      }
      $content->more = array(
        'href' => 'catalog/all_products-tax-term',
        'title' => 'See All',
        'query' => array(
          'field_catalog_tid' => $tids,
        )
      );
    }

  }

  if ($pane->subtype == 'view-name_featured_resources_and') {
    if ($content->delta == 'view-name_featured_resources_and-block_2') {
      if ($context['argument_term_1']->data) {
        $tids = array();
        $tids[] = $context['argument_term_1']->data->tid;
        $content->more = array(
          'href' => 'catalog/all_products-tax-term',
          'title' => 'See All',
          'query' => array(
            'field_catalog_tid' => $tids,
          )
        );
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to use Contextual Filters (or, the functionality formerly known as Arguments").

Expand the "advanced" fieldset on the right side of your View's admin panel.

If, for example, I select "Content:Type" as a contextual filter, and my main page output of the view has a path of "/testview" then I can go to "/testview/Page" and see all content of type "Page". Same with my other content types, which happen to be "Story", "Product", and "Slide". You can do this with features besides content type. It sounds like using taxonomy terms would meet your needs.

Comment: This may have worked, but I never got around to trying it. You'll see the more complex solution a coworker came up with. Thanks though!